# PHP : select multiple count(id) from MySQL as one query

Tags: php, mysql, select, joomla

I need to optimize the following code in one query :

```
        $query = 'select count(id) as featured_ads from #___properties  WHERE featured = 1 and approved =1';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $featured_ads = intval($db->loadResult());


    $query = 'select count(id) as wait_ads from #___properties  WHERE approved =0 and canceled<>"1" ';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $wait_ads = intval($db->loadResult());


    $query = 'select count(id) as total_users from #__sresuad WHERE gid = 18 ';
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $total_users = intval($db->loadResult());
```

What should I do?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? You may also want to consider using the Joomla API for your query and escaping values, which you're currently not doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the counts to be returned in one query? A simple way to address this is to just have all your SELECTs define fields for an outer SELECT:

```
SELECT
    (select count(id) from #___properties  WHERE featured = 1 and approved =1) AS featured_ads,
    (select count(id) from #___properties  WHERE approved =0 and canceled<>"1") AS wait_ads,
    (select count(id) from #__sresuad WHERE gid = 18) AS total_users
```

As suggested by Lodder in his comment, writing SQL queries by hand is prone to errors and security lapses, so you might want to avoid it if possible.